# No such file to load -- ruby-mbox (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I ran:

```
sudo gem install ruby-mbox
```

Then:

```
require "rubygems"
require "ruby-mbox"

mbox = Mbox.new("Inbox")
```

And got this:

```
$ ruby mbox_read.rb 
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- ruby-mbox (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from mbox_read.rb:2
```

Gem server says:

```
ruby-mbox 0.0.2 [rdoc] [www]
A simple library to read mbox files. 
Executables are mbox-daemon, mbox-do.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using:

```
require 'mbox'
```

would work better?

Here's [an example](https://github.com/meh/ruby-mbox/blob/master/examples/count.rb) from the site...